# \x0D\x0A character is appended in hbase table data

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, hadoop2

I am creating row key in HBase using combination of three columns.
It is getting inserted successfully and i can see my data in the log also .
The data in the log is correct without any junk character .
But when i scan my table i can see \x0D\x0A is getting appended in the row key

```
 123|\x0D\x0A4295856150|404                 column=cf:SegmentSequence, timestamp=1476249090712, value=2
 123|\x0D\x0A4295856150|404                 column=cf:SegmentSequence.segmentId, timestamp=1476249090712, value=15
 123|\x0D\x0A4295856150|405                 column=cf:FFAction, timestamp=1476249090712, value=I
```

also.
This is how i form my row key.

```
String strKey = strFileName + "|" + strOrgId + "|" + strLineItemId;
Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(strKey));
```

Also this character is getting appended before strOrgId  and after strFileName .

Comment: It is carriage return followed by new line. That is the reason you are not seeing those in logs. You can trim the string strFileName to solve it.

Comment: I trimmed and was able to display record in one line .Even if it is 5 character then also those character was getting displayed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that in strOrgId there is new line character(\r\n whose toBytes() value is \x0D\x0A) in the start as per data sample. So you need to trim all the string individually that contains new line and then concatenate or need to replace all new line characters with blank. Below is trim code for only strOrgId as per data sample.

```
String strKey = strFileName + "|" + strOrgId.trim() + "|" + strLineItemId;
```